# In am charts how i remove legend label or need to shown "no values" when am getting 0 Value

Tags: javascript, amcharts

amcharts how I remove legend label or show "no values" when am **getting 0 Value** [image] .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [`valueFunction`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend#valueFunction) inside your legend to customize what value is displayed upon hover. Here's an example that does what you're asking:

```
  "legend": {
    // ...
    "valueFunction": function(graphDataItem, valueText) {
      if (graphDataItem.values) { 
        if (graphDataItem.values.value === 0) {
          valueText = "no values"
        }
      }
      return valueText;
    }
  },
```

**Edit**

Since you didn't indicate that you were using `periodValueText` (which is why posting a working fiddle helps out a lot), you can still use valueFunction to check the valueText to see if it's "0 kWH" or whatever string you want to replace with "no values":

```
"valueFunction": function(graphDataItem, valueText) {
  if (graphDataItem.values) { 
    if (graphDataItem.values.value === 0 || graphDataItem.values.value === undefined) {
      valueText = "no values"
    }
  }
  else if (valueText === "0 kWH") {
    valueText = "no values";
  }
  return valueText;
}
```

Updated demo below:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "legend": {
    "periodValueText": "[[value.sum]] kWH",
    "valueText": "[[value]] kWH",
    "valueFunction": function(graphDataItem, valueText) {
      if (graphDataItem.values) { 
    if (graphDataItem.values.value === 0 || graphDataItem.values.value === undefined) {
          valueText = "no values"
        }
      }
      else if (valueText === "0 kWH") {
        valueText = "no values";
      }
      return valueText;
    },
    "position": "right"
  },
  "chartCursor": {},
  "graphs": [{ 
    "title": "First graph",
    "valueField": "value1"
  },{ 
    "title": "Second graph",
    "valueField": "value2"
  }, {
    "title": "Third graph",
    "valueField": "value3"
  }],
  "categoryField": "category",
  "dataProvider": [
    {
        "category": "cat-1",
        "value2": 5,
        "value1": 0
    },
    {
        "category": "cat-2",
        "value2": 8,
        "value1": 5
    },
    {
        "category": "cat-3",
        "value2": 20,
        "value1": 1
    },
    {
        "category": "cat-4",
        "value2": 20,
        "value1": 8
    },
    {
        "category": "cat-5",
        "value2": 17,
        "value1": 4
    },
    {
        "category": "cat-6",
        "value2": 0,
        "value1": 10
    },
    {
        "category": "cat-7",
        "value2": 11,
        "value1": 6
    },
    {
        "category": "cat-8",
        "value2": 0,
        "value1": 9
    },
    {
        "category": "cat-9",
        "value2": 8,
        "value1": 0
    },
    {
        "category": "cat-10",
        "value2": 15,
        "value1": 7
    }
]
});
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 250px;"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, @xorspark..But I have faced one issue the no values show the cursor point actions only.But initially, it's shown 0 value only, here with I have attached my code also =>  'legend': {
                        'position': 'top',
                        'periodValueText': legendPeriodTemplate(src.data),
                        'labelText': '[[title]] :',
                        'valueText': legendTemplate(src.data),
                        'valueFunction': function (graphDataItem, valueText) {
//code
                    },

Comment: You didn't indicate that you were using periodValueText. This is why you post your code in a fiddle for all of your questions instead of a screenshot. What's the return value from legendPeriodTemplate? Is it `[[value.sum]]`? I can't tell from your code. For the future, you should make an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can help you easier without any back and forth. That said - I updated the valueFunction. You can have it check your valueText for "0 kWH" or whatever you want to filter out and replace with "no values".

Comment: Thanks, @xorspark..Working Fine

Answer (score 0):

**Try using**

To catch the add listener

```
chart.addListener('rendered', function(event) {
  // populate our custom legend when chart renders
  chart.customLegend = document.getElementById('legend');
  for (var i in chart.chartData) {
    var row = chart.chartData[i];
    var color = chart.colors[i];
    var percent = Math.round(row.percents * 100) / 100;
    var value = row.value;
    legend.innerHTML += '<div class="legend-item" id="legend-item-' + i + '" onclick="toggleSlice(' + i + ');" onmouseover="hoverSlice(' + i + ');" onmouseout="blurSlice(' + i + ');" style="color: ' + color + ';"><div class="legend-marker" style="background: ' + color + '"></div>' + row.title + '<div class="legend-value">' + value + ' | ' + percent + '%</div></div>';
  }
});
```

**More details can be found here [http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/26ca99ef667e85949ba80bb02d9391aa]**

Comment: @tamil-selvan-c Youcan customize/ apply your conditions accordingly.